# HackerRank N series, Terminated due to timeout

Tags: java, timeout

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/summing-the-n-series
I tried to optimize the running time by just calculating the sum up to the maximum input once but still I got a time out when running against really large inputs (like [this one](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/2147/input03.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1481088872&Signature=f7rM8fwrZBHeq6qomQRTWHzg%2F0Q%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)). Is there a way to improve my code? Or a simple yet more effective approach to this problem?

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numLine = scan.nextInt();
        List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int line = 0; line < numLine; line++) { input.add(scan.nextInt()); }
        scan.close();

        int max = Collections.max(input);
        int i = 1;
        long sum = 0;
        while (i <= max) {
            sum = sum + 2*i - 1;  // n*n - (n-1)*(n-1) = 2*n - 1
            result.add(sum);
            i++;
         }
        for (int num : input) {
             System.out.println(result.get(num-1));
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: One idea would be to use `BufferedReader` instead of `Scanner`. I always use `BufferedReader` in competitive programming.

Comment: see ans here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53960585/3154636