# Java : Summing the N series fails due to timeout

Tags: java, biginteger

In hackerrank website there is a task called Summing the N series Under Mathematics section. Here is link for the same https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/summing-the-n-series/problem

I have tried many things. Finally came to point where some of my test cases are passing some are not due to timeout exception.

Here is the complete code. Please let me know what would be solution.

```
public class Solution {

    static int mod = 1000000007;

    static int summingSeries(long t) { 
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            sum = ((t%mod)*(t%mod))%mod;
        }
        return (int)sum;
    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int t = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().trim());

        for (int tItr = 0; tItr < t; tItr++) {
            long n = Long.parseLong(scanner.nextLine().trim());

            int result = summingSeries(n);

            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }

        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What test case are you failing?

Comment: this are few examples `5351871996120528`,`2248813659738258`... which is in test case no 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: A lot of Hachernak test aren't just about writing algorithms, it's about thinking around them and their problematics. Your test is failing because you're brute-forcing it, try to find more information on mathematics behind arithmetics sums, modulo and the given value (10^7 + 7).

Comment: Can you tell us what's wrong?

If I were to guess, you are using an `int` to evaluate a really large number. that is, the `n.intValue()` call. Take note that the input `n` can be equal to 10^16 while the `int` max value is only somewhere between 10^9 and 10^10

Comment: Additionally, there is a better way on solving series problems without iterating through the entire series. Im not sure if it's ethical to share the solution because the nature of your question seems to be from a competitive site

Comment: I have changed some code and now only test case 5 and 6 are failing due to timeout.

Comment: @KaNa0011 Yes I saw that ans. It works but I don't want to change their main method.

Comment: I don't get it. What does the loop in summingSeries do, except calculating the same value over and over? Oh, I see you found out.

Comment: I was doing lot of R&D on code. Then Finally I realise that I need to focus on math problem not on programming then I simply maths and came simplified expression as `n^2 % 1000000007`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it got solved. take a look.

```
public class Solution {
    static int mod = 1000000007;
    static int summingSeries(long n) { 
        return (int)(((n % mod) * (n % mod)) % mod);
    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int t = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().trim());

        for (int tItr = 0; tItr < t; tItr++) {
            long n = Long.parseLong(scanner.nextLine().trim());

            int result = summingSeries(n);

            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }

        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```